# recasting array, last value always triggers an invalid read exception

Tags: c, arrays, valgrind

I have a function that recasts a bunch of float32 values to int32, and it works up until the very last float32 that it tries to read. even if that float is not the last value in the array (ie I set the FOR loop to stop early) it still returns an invalid read as if it was trying to read outside the array.

```
int i, nvoxels;
nvoxels = roi->dim[1] * roi->dim[2] * roi->dim[3];
for (i = 0; i<nvoxels; i++) {
    roiData[i] = (int)round(((double *)(roi->data))[i]); //line 400
}
```

roidata is defined outside the recast function as:

```
int* roiData = MallocAndCheck(sizeof(int) * roi->dim[1] * roi->dim[2] * roi->dim[3], 1);
```

roiData is a new array that is meant to hold the int values that are taken from roi->data (which is a void* with a bunch of pointer values in it). in the above, we are taking the double * from roi->data, rounding their value, and casting that as an int to store within roiData. I have confirmed multiple times that the error is not tied to explicitly reading outside roi-> data (it should have 1,048,576 values within it, and it'll process 1,048,576 values), but the error still happens even if I tell it to stop at 20,000 values. there is no other code after the for besides a return 0/1 statement.

(MallocAndCheck is a custom memory function that wraps together malloc, null pointer checking, and pointer registration so that I can easily cleanup on exit. we can assume it is working properly) it's prototype is MallocAndCheck(int size, int shouldRegister) (where should register is whether or not it should keep track of the pointer for cleanup on exit, or I will handle cleanup manually).

```
==13348== Invalid read of size 8
==13348==    at 0x402293: nii_recast_to_int32 (pow_filter.c:400)
==13348==    by 0x402293: RecastRoi (pow_filter.c:313)
==13348==    by 0x401450: main (pow_filter.c:50)
==13348==  Address 0x5a03040 is 0 bytes after a block of size 4,194,304 alloc'd
==13348==    at 0x4C2FB55: calloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==13348==    by 0x4109F9: nifti_image_load (nifti1_io.c:4547)
==13348==    by 0x417CF7: nifti_image_read (nifti1_io.c:3904)
==13348==    by 0x401EBF: OpenNiftiImageFile (pow_filter.c:271)
==13348==    by 0x4013EA: main (pow_filter.c:46)
```

this only ever triggers on the very last data read, no matter where in the array you stop. (roi is the pointer returned by the "nifti" functions).

edit: extra information:

roi is defined as:

```
typedef struct {                /*!< Image storage struct **/

  int ndim ;                    /*!< last dimension greater than 1 (1..7) */
  int nx ;                      /*!< dimensions of grid array 0            */
  int ny ;                      /*!< dimensions of grid array 1           */
  int nz ;                      /*!< dimensions of grid array 2           */
  int nt ;                      /*!< dimensions of grid array 3           */
  int nu ;                      /*!< dimensions of grid array 4           */
  int nv ;                      /*!< dimensions of grid array 5           */
  int nw ;                      /*!< dimensions of grid array 6           */
  int dim[8] ;                  /*!< dim[0]=ndim, dim[1]=nx, etc.         */
  size_t nvox ;                    /*!< number of voxels = nx*ny*nz*...*nw   */
  int nbyper ;                  /*!< bytes per voxel, matches datatype    */
  int datatype ;                /*!< type of data in voxels: DT_* code    */

  float dx ;                    /*!< grid spacings      */
  float dy ;                    /*!< grid spacings      */
  float dz ;                    /*!< grid spacings      */
  float dt ;                    /*!< grid spacings      */
  float du ;                    /*!< grid spacings      */
  float dv ;                    /*!< grid spacings      */
  float dw ;                    /*!< grid spacings      */
  float pixdim[8] ;             /*!< pixdim[1]=dx, etc. */

  float scl_slope ;             /*!< scaling parameter - slope        */
  float scl_inter ;             /*!< scaling parameter - intercept    */

  float cal_min ;               /*!< calibration parameter, minimum   */
  float cal_max ;               /*!< calibration parameter, maximum   */

  int qform_code ;              /*!< codes for (x,y,z) space meaning  */
  int sform_code ;              /*!< codes for (x,y,z) space meaning  */

  int freq_dim  ;               /*!< indexes (1,2,3, or 0) for MRI    */
  int phase_dim ;               /*!< directions in dim[]/pixdim[]     */
  int slice_dim ;               /*!< directions in dim[]/pixdim[]     */

  int   slice_code  ;           /*!< code for slice timing pattern    */
  int   slice_start ;           /*!< index for start of slices        */
  int   slice_end   ;           /*!< index for end of slices          */
  float slice_duration ;        /*!< time between individual slices   */

  /*! quaternion transform parameters
  [when writing a dataset, these are used for qform, NOT qto_xyz]   */
  float quatern_b , quatern_c , quatern_d ,
    qoffset_x , qoffset_y , qoffset_z ,
    qfac      ;

  mat44 qto_xyz ;               /*!< qform: transform (i,j,k) to (x,y,z) */
  mat44 qto_ijk ;               /*!< qform: transform (x,y,z) to (i,j,k) */

  mat44 sto_xyz ;               /*!< sform: transform (i,j,k) to (x,y,z) */
  mat44 sto_ijk ;               /*!< sform: transform (x,y,z) to (i,j,k) */

  float toffset ;               /*!< time coordinate offset */

  int xyz_units  ;              /*!< dx,dy,dz units: NIFTI_UNITS_* code  */
  int time_units ;              /*!< dt       units: NIFTI_UNITS_* code  */

  int nifti_type ;              /*!< 0==ANALYZE, 1==NIFTI-1 (1 file),
                                             2==NIFTI-1 (2 files),
                                             3==NIFTI-ASCII (1 file) */
  int   intent_code ;           /*!< statistic type (or something)       */
  float intent_p1 ;             /*!< intent parameters                   */
  float intent_p2 ;             /*!< intent parameters                   */
  float intent_p3 ;             /*!< intent parameters                   */
  char  intent_name[16] ;       /*!< optional description of intent data */

  char descrip[80]  ;           /*!< optional text to describe dataset   */
  char aux_file[24] ;           /*!< auxiliary filename                  */

  char *fname ;                 /*!< header filename (.hdr or .nii)         */
  char *iname ;                 /*!< image filename  (.img or .nii)         */
  int   iname_offset ;          /*!< offset into iname where data starts    */
  int   swapsize ;              /*!< swap unit in image data (might be 0)   */
  int   byteorder ;             /*!< byte order on disk (MSB_ or LSB_FIRST) */
  void *data ;                  /*!< pointer to data: nbyper*nvox bytes     */

  int                num_ext ;  /*!< number of extensions in ext_list       */
  nifti1_extension * ext_list ; /*!< array of extension structs (with data) */
  analyze_75_orient_code analyze75_orient; /*!< for old analyze files, orient */

} nifti_image ;
```

as you can see nifti_image->data is a void* whose stored data type is nifti_image->datatype.

earlier in my code I check the datatype which is where the above code is directed too, which does the above operations on it.

in this specific case I know the datatype SHOULD be float32.

Comment: I don't see any float32 defined anywhere. There is double, which is rarely a 32-bit type. 1 million doubles will generally take 8 million bytes, while valgrind says only 4 million bytes are allocated. You are going out of bounds when trying to read a million values. I don't see any evidence of the violation happening after less than the full number of reads. Please show some evidence, i.e. code and associated valgrind log. Compile with debug info so that valgrind could show line numbers.

Comment: @n.m.

you actually bring up a very good point that I didn't consider. I used double* because I simply looked at the way the program I am rewriting already handled this exact issue, and they used double*. switching it to float* makes the error stop, but I'm still verifying that the data integrity is upheld.

I'm wondering if this is an error out of the fact that the original library I'm referencing was built for 32bit, and I'm building for 64bit. shot in the dark, but any chance you know a decent reference on changes considerations of migrating from 32-64?

Comment: 32-64 doesn't affect sizes of floating point types, only integers and pointers. Don't know any references, sorry.